# How to split strings in a list of lists

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have lists in a list, shown below:

```
ls = [["Test1\t\t\t\t\tValue1"],["Test2\t\t\t\t\t\t\tValue2"]]

# My current code is 
new = [i.split("\t") for i in ls]
```

Desired Output:

```
[["Test1","Value1"],["Test2","Value2]]
```

It doesn't seem to be working, the current output for Test1 shows:

```
["Test1\t\t\t\t","Value1"]
```

Comment: Do you expect each inner list to hold one element only?

Comment: It's impossible that you get this output by running the presented code. You should get an `AttributeError` instead as lists don't have `split` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd actually approach this with reducing all the `\t` first to something manageable, i.e. just one space, the split it afterwards:

```
import re

ls = [["Test1\t\t\t\t\tValue1"],["Test2\t\t\t\t\t\t\tValue2"]]
new_list = [
    re.sub('\t+', " ", val[0]).split(" ")
    for val in ls
]
```

This uses `re.sub` to replace all `\t` with a single space (you can change this to something else if it conflicts with your data) then uses `split` split the updated string;

See [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

**Explanation (val[0])**:

Since your original `ls` is compose of single element arrays, i.e. `["Test1\t\t\t\t\tValue1"]` we need to reference the value inside of it first before we can perform string functions on it. So looking at our list comprehension, `for val in ls` iterates over your `ls` where each `val` is a single element array, hence `val[0]` will give us the value `"Test1\t\t\t\t\tValue1"`.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
# empty string's evaluates to false, skip.

new = [[j for j in i[0].split("\t") if j] for i in ls]
```

### Output

```
[['Test1', 'Value1'], ['Test2', 'Value2']]
```

### Explanation (`j for j in i[0].split if j` portion)

`i[0]` to access first element of the list `["Test1\t\t\t\t\tValue1"]` then apply split on it will return `['Test1', '', '', '', '', 'Value1']` & `if j` to ignore those white spaces that gets created while splitting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind working with sets, you could try:

```
ls = [["Test1\t\t\t\t\tValue1"],["Test2\t\t\t\t\t\t\tValue2"],["Value3\t\t\t\tTest3"]]

new = [(set(i[0].split('\t'))) for i in ls] # using sets to reduce empty strings
[i.remove('') for i in new]  # removing empty string
new = [list(i) for i in new]  # reverting the sets to lists
[i.sort() for i in new]  # restoring order in values
new
```

Output:

```
[['Test1', 'Value1'], ['Test2', 'Value2'], ['Test3', 'Value3']]
```